# DDR3 1333 memory modules will operate in overclocking mode

Tags: motherboard, overclocking, ddr3

I'm going to upgrade RAM in a dated desktop computer with [ASRock G41C-GS R2.0 board](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/G41C-GS%20R2.0.pdf) and [Intel Q9400](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDxa3rx9TMAhUqKpoKHb_GDFEQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fark.intel.com%2Fproducts%2F35365%2FIntel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9400-6M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB&usg=AFQjCNFCzv2zmgjNK3j0lhO_iJ3pI8FJig&sig2=ereG1tf3jXPVu2XVxdqVSg) CPU.

I've found that DDR3 1333MHz should work with that CPU and the board supports up to 8GB of them. 
I don't understand the warning

> DDR3 1333 memory modules will operate in overclocking mode

found on the p. 8 of the user manual (see link above) though.

Is it just that the overclocking jumper needs to be set or **are there some other risks**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, over-clocking RAM **frequency** simply requires CPU and RAM is able to operate at that frequency, and that the Board supports an [SPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect)/[XMP](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/extreme-memory-profile-xmp.html) profile that supports the new frequency.

Since your CPU and RAM support 1333MHz, and the motherboard supports the OC required per the documentation (pg 6), it shoudl work fine, but observe the CPU and system temperature after making your change, to ensure everything is thermally stable.

One thing to be extra cautious about when overclocking RAM, is Voltage. In this case it does not appear that you will be modifying the voltage, so there is little risk that the RAM or other system components will be damaged, as long as the system cooling is sufficient to the task.

Comment: Thanks. Before accepting the answer... Why is the RAM overclocked? It is already 1333MHz (as you wrote) and the overclocking just makes FSB run at that frequency.

Comment: FSB is arbitrated by the SPD specifications available from the motherboard. SPD detects the RAM physical speed, and the system bus speed, and selects a set of timings and transfer rate from the SPD profile list. SPD is based on JEDEC specifications. Intel introduced the XMP profile extensions to SPD to enable overclocking, so its like a faster SPD profile. Your motherboard is quite old, so the JEDEC specs available did not yet allow 1333, so an XMP profile was added to the motherboard which can run at that frequency.

Comment: Note that the RAM is not overclocked, the SPD is, so that the RAM can be used at full 1333MHz. The motherboard does not natively support the JEDEC profiles for ram at that speed, so you must set the jumper, which activates some additional hardware the manufacturer built into the motherboard to accommodate. Otherwise the SPD will downclock the ram freq to 1066 or 800MHz with all the timings that implies. The CPU and the RAM support 1333 (which is good because OC would be impossible if they didn't) but the motherbard does not, by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is not telling you that you **have to** use overclocking.

It is informing you that is **will work** if you choose to use the overclocking mode (or if you are already using it).

If you are not overclocking, it is not a concern.